# Stripe Custom receipt

Tags: stripe-payments

How do we use our own custom receipt for checkout session in stripe. It is mentioned in the document for customisation. Still no code reference to do so. Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "custom receipts", but you can choose to send a receipt to an email address of your choosing with Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-receipt_email

If you want to send your own emails, you'd disable Stripe emails in your [dashboard settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/emails) and send your own email when you receive the `checkout.session.completed` webhook event.